# TableDirections bug?

Tags: bugs, formatting

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.0**

---

Here is the example in the `TableDirections` documentation:

```
TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, TableDirections -> Row]
```

If I enter this in a Mma 10.3 notebook (Win 10), the following message appears:

> The specified setting for the option GridBoxOptions, RowAlignments cannot be used.

Is this the obvious problem it seems?  Is it fixed in 10.4?

Comment: I still see the same message in MMA 10.4.0 on Win7-64. The output is correct though.

Comment: In 9.0 it works fine, in 10.0 it already shows the error (while formatting correctly).

Comment: MMA 10.4.1, Win10-64bit, same message ... with correct output

Comment: Quiet does not fix it either, in 10.4.1 Window 64-bit.